# Kafka Direct API Batch Input Size

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-directconsumer

As per Kafka Direct API number of input records is calculated as

```
maxInputSize = maxRatePerPartition * #numOfPartitions# * #BATCH_DURATION_SECONDS#
```

I am really failed to understand why input size is determined like this. Suppose my job processes 100 files in 5 minutes.

if I set maxRatePerPartition = 1, numOfPartitions in my topic are 6, what should be batch duration because if I set batch duration seconds to 300, I will be fetching 1800 files as input and there will be a long queue of batches waiting to be processed and 1800 files will take about half hour to process let aside memory issues and other constraints.

How can I cater this issue. I should be able to control records in my input. I can process 10 records in 5 minutes, I should be able to load these many records only.